# Uncaught Reference Error: Activexobject is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the activexobject in my project it works fine in IE. I know this is the microsoft control. I want to run the project in Mozila and Chrome but it showing the error as Activexobject is not defined.

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
```

Comment: In which programmer language did you write this source code line? It looks like VB.net or classic JScript.

Comment: Lemme guess...http://www.sitepoint.com/server-side-xml-javascript/ ?I used that tutorial...and I'm having the same error. If this isn't a good way to do it, his code is obviously broken and untested.

Answer (score 0):

FireFox and Chrome doesn't support any ActiveX objects by default, so it is no wonder why you get this error message. For FireFox browser there is a way, but not recommended. See [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=564636).

What do you want to aproach? Tell us more and / or show us source code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, yeah, a nifty little caveat of this method is that it only works on IE. (And unlike what the dude in the tutorial I posted in my comment above said, it is NOT XML's fault. It's ActiveX.)

Here's a comparison of three methods. I'm going to try the third to solve my XML reading problem...

http://www.steveborn.com/codenotes/LoadingXML.htm